# is there any way to define jar start up arguments in apache flink

Tags: java

I am using apache flink 1.10 to compute my stream data, now I want to integrete Apollo(a configuration management tool about apps) to manage my config. The apollo docs tells me I could pass app.id by :

```
-Dapp.id=YOUR-APP-ID
```

so now I trying to add startup parameter to my app, but the flink is upload jar file and run automaticly like this:

[image]

. so what should I do to add a startup parameter of this app? this is my gradle config:

```
project(":rdw-flinkjob-consume") {

    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

    archivesBaseName = "rdw-flinkjob-consume"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    group = 'com.sportswin.rdw'
    mainClassName = 'com.sportswin.rdw.WalletConsumeRealtimeHandler'
    description = """Flink Quickstart Job"""

    // NOTE: We cannot use "compileOnly" or "shadow" configurations since then we could not run code
    // in the IDE or with "gradle run". We also cannot exclude transitive dependencies from the
    // shadowJar yet (see https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/159).
    // -> Explicitly define the // libraries we want to be included in the "flinkShadowJar" configuration!
    configurations {
        flinkShadowJar // dependencies which go into the shadowJar

        // always exclude these (also from transitive dependencies) since they are provided by Flink
        // flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'org.apache.flink', module: 'force-shading'
        flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
        flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
        flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'log4j'
    }

    dependencies {
        flinkShadowJar project(":rdw-flinkjob-common")
    }


// make compileOnly dependencies available for tests:
    sourceSets {
        main.compileClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
        main.runtimeClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar

        test.compileClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
        test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar

        javadoc.classpath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
    }

    run.classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Built-By': System.getProperty('user.name'),
                    'Build-Jdk': System.getProperty('java.version')
        }
    }

    shadowJar {
        configurations = [project.configurations.flinkShadowJar]
    }
}
```

now the server's log always tell me that I am not pass the `app.id` into it like this:

```
2020-04-30 12:44:13,146 WARN  com.ctrip.framework.apollo.internals.AbstractConfigRepository  - Sync config failed, will retry. Repository class com.ctrip.framework.apollo.internals.RemoteConfigRepository, reason: Load Apollo Config failed - appId: ApolloNoAppIdPlaceHolder, cluster: default, namespace: application, url: http://172.30.184.6:8080/configs/ApolloNoAppIdPlaceHolder/default/application?ip=172.30.184.16 [Cause: [status code: 404] Could not find config for namespace - appId: ApolloNoAppIdPlaceHolder, cluster: default, namespace: application, please check whether the configs are released in Apollo!]
2020-04-30 12:44:17,306 WARN  com.ctrip.framework.apollo.util.ConfigUtil                    - app.id is not set, please make sure it is set in classpath:/META-INF/app.properties, now apollo will only load public namespace configurations!
2020-04-30 12:44:18,337 WARN  com.ctrip.framework.apollo.util.ConfigUtil                    - app.id is not set, please make sure it is set in classpath:/META-INF/app.properties, now apollo will only load public namespace configurations!
2020-04-30 12:44:18,346 WARN  com.ctrip.framework.apollo.internals.RemoteConfigRepository   - Load config failed, will retry in 1 SECONDS. appId: ApolloNoAppIdPlaceHolder, cluster: default, namespaces: application
2020-04-30 12:44:19,354 WARN  com.ctrip.framework.apollo.internals.AbstractConfigRepository  - Sync config failed, will retry. Repository class com.ctrip.framework.apollo.internals.RemoteConfigRepository, reason: Load Apollo Config failed - appId: ApolloNoAppIdPlaceHolder, cluster: default, namespace: application, url: http://172.30.184.6:8080/configs/ApolloNoAppIdPlaceHolder/default/application?ip=172.30.184.16 [Cause: [status code: 404] Could not find config for namespace - appId: ApolloNoAppIdPlaceHolder, cluster: default, namespace: application, please check whether the configs are released in Apollo!]
2020-04-30 12:44:34,440 WARN  com.ctrip.framework.apollo.util.ConfigUtil                    - app.id is not set, please make sure it is set in classpath:/META-INF/app.properties, now apollo will only load public namespace configurations!
```

Answer (score 0):

in your build.gradle file, add this:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dapp.id=0010020015"]
```

works.